# Liner models: what is this model called?

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear-model

Let $$Y_{ij}=\beta_0+U_{0j}+\beta_1X_{ij}+U_{1i}X_{ij}+e_i$$
be a linear model. Where $i=1,2,...,n$, $j=1,2,...,r$. $U_{0j}$~$N(0,\sigma^2_{u})$ and $U_{1j}$~$N(0,\sigma^2_{u_{1}})$. $\beta_0+\beta_1X_{ij}$ is fixed and $U_{0j}+U_{0j}$ is random.

1. what is this model called?
2. what is really fixed and random in this model? Parameters or exogenous variables?
3. what is the difference with a standard regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is this model called?

This is a mixed effects model. In particular it has random intercepts for the grouping factor $U_0$  and random slopes for $X$

> what is really fixed and random in this model? Parameters or exogenous variables?

In the frequentist mixed model,  the $\beta$ are considered fixed and the $U$ (and $e$) are random.

> what is the difference with a standard regression?

It depends on what you mean by "standard" but assuming you mean a model with only fixed effects, estimated by ordinary least squares, then the difference is considerable. Estimation of the mixed model is very different than for the "standard" model. In mixed models we need to estimate variances for the random effects as well as, potentially, correlations between them. This makes the likelihood function quite complex and typically it will not have a closed form solution, as the "standard" model has.